# Caliburn.Micro and Simple Injector - InjectProperties is deprecated - How to BuildUp()?

Tags: dependency-injection, caliburn.micro, simple-injector

Simple Injectors function to `InjectProperties` is marked deprecated and will be removed in a future release. How will I be able to use it in Caliburn.Micro's `BuildUp` override? The framework uses this internally via `IoC.BuildUp` many times!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `InjectProperties` is marked with the `[Obsolete]` attribute and the compiler message points to the URL https://simpleinjector.org/depr1 which gives more detailed information. The referenced page explains why this method is deprecated and how to change your code or configuration for this.

That page also links to the [Property Injection paragraph of the Extendibility Points page](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extensibility.html#overriding-property-injection-behavior). This page describes how to configure the container to enable property injection. For instance:

```cs
class PropertySelectionBehavior<TAttribute> : IPropertySelectionBehavior
    where TAttribute : Attribute
{
    public bool SelectProperty(Type type, PropertyInfo prop) {
        return prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TAttribute)).Any();
    }
}

// Usage:
var container = new Container();
container.Options.PropertySelectionBehavior = 
    new PropertySelectionBehavior<MyInjectAttribute>();
```

This allows the container to inject properties that are marked explicitly with the `[MyInject]` attribute.

When possible, always try to let the container create the type for you instead of having types with a default constructor and injecting properties after that. I'm however unfamiliar with Caliburn Micro and I'm not sure if that's possible.

In case you need BuildUp like behavior, you can retrieve a registration from the container and request it to initialize an existing instance for you. That would look as follows:

```cs
public void BuildUp(object instance)
{
    var registration = this.container.GetRegistration(instance.GetType(), true);
    registration.Registration.InitializeInstance(instance);
}
```

This allows the container to initialize instances and send it through the [Simple Injector pipeline](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pipeline.html) which enables property injection and other initialization according to the given registration and configuration rules (such as the explicit property injection example given above).

This works great if the types that need to be built up have a default constructor. If this is not the case, you will have to create (and cache) a new `Registration` instance by calling `Lifestyle.Transient.CreateRegistration` and call the `InitializeInstance` on that instance, just as the `SimpleInjectorFilterAttributeFilterProvider` of the MVC integration package does (you can take a look at its source code [here](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#SimpleInjector.Integration.Web.Mvc/SimpleInjectorFilterAttributeFilterProvider.cs)).

Comment: Thanks Steven for that quick response. I actually read that link but didn't know a way to run an instance that was created externally of the container through the containers pipeline.

Comment: I worry a bit though, that there are types being used that are not registered in the container - only their properties. This is all within the framework, I am unsure about the inner workings...

Comment: @MarkusHütter: I'm not experienced with Caliburn and WPF, and not sure what to suggest here. Can you update your question of give me a link to some online resource that explains what types need to be 'built up' and how they are used?

Comment: hmm, I had only been looking at the usages that resharper was showing. Looking for documentation I found: "“BuildUp” is optionally used to supply property dependencies to instances of IResult that are executed by the framework. "   Looking through the code, classes supplied by the framework that inherit IResult don't even have injectable properties. So I guess I would be fine registering my own IResult classes and use your suggestion via `InitializeInstance(...)`

Comment: thanks for the help. I think you don't even get enough credit for all of these thorough answers you provide. All these questions seem so specific and no one else but you seems to answer them (concerning Simple Injector)!

Comment: @MarkusHütter: After reading [this documentation](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=IResult%20and%20Coroutines), it seems to me that you should not have to build up `IResult` instances. IResult implementations are normal services and if they require dependencies, you should wire their dependencies as usual using constructor injection. And even if you want to revert to property injection on those IResult services, you can still let Simple Injector resolve those services for you. I don't see any reason for building up those types.

Comment: No, let me correct that. The example uses the `[Import]` attribute and initializes those classes with runtime values. I would argue that all logic should be extracted from such result class into its own service. You can inject that single service together with the runtime value into the constructor and this prevents you from having to do any property injection at all. Or you might even be able to completely extra the logic of the `GoForward` into its own component. There are multiple ways, but like I said, I'm too unexperienced with WPF to know what would work best.

Comment: yeah, I think this can all be handled with constructor injection and the override of `BuildUp` isn't actually even needed!